# Apache Zeppelin : How to publish whole report to website

Tags: web, publish, apache-zeppelin

After connecting to the PostgreSql Database and retrieving specific data, some (5) visualisations were made. Instead of publishing each paragraph (Each individual visualisation) to a website, is there a way of publishing the whole report (obtained while viewing the notebook in report view)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is quite useful feature. I would welcome something like that. 
I was thinking about exactly same thing. I needed to publish 4 simple visualizations at once. After some attempts I found way how to solve this.

As a first step I just created one last paragraph on the end of my notebook which had interpreter displaying HTML. I used pyspark by:

```
print("""%html ... """)
```

Then I created simple HTML table layout like this:

```
   <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 50%;">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 50%;">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

(I am not HTML professional, so I just used HTML generator for this).
After layout was generated, I populated all cells with each paragraph iframe link I needed to display. As example, one cell of table looks like this:

```
<td style="width: 50%;"><iframe src=LINK_WHICH_YOU_GET_BY_PUBLISHING_PARAGRAPH width="100%" height="400"></iframe></td>
```

There is more parameters how you can play/tune within that HTML table and with iframes, but it require some HTML skills.

When all cells of the HTML table are populated just try to run the HTML in that very last paragraph of your notebook. If outcome is OK then just publish this lash paragraph and you have one link to your all visualizations.